# running a python flask webapp on apache

Tags: apache, flask

I'm trying to run a flask app on apache on ubuntu.
I'm getting this error in the browser:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

the apache log does not indicate any error eventhough the log level is debug.
My wsgi file looks like:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myflask/')
from run import app as application
```

I've also tried:

```
from appimport app as application
```

without any luck.
If I change the wsgi file content to:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

then it works.
Also, if I run the 3 lines of my wsgi in a python console, it does not throw any exception.
I have a run.py scrpt that can run the app with it's own standalone server just fine as below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Here is the filesystem:

```
├── app
│   ├── db_access.py
│   ├── db_access.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── myapp.wsgi
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
├── run.pyc
```

any ideas how to make it run on apache?
I've already read:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

http://fosshelp.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-deploy-flask-application-with.html

Comment: I had several problems running Python scripts when needed something different from "python app.py". Then I figured out how a Python software should look like, and created a tool called Machete (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/machete/). You can give it a try, creating a empty (but runnable) flask app, and then try to integrate with your Apache configuration... it may work. Python software structure is kind of tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.
Instead of targeting run.py in the wsgi, I targeted the views.py which has the route tags.
Another issue was that my sqlite database did not have the proper permissions which caused the app to fail but you would not get any errors.
To see errors, I had to add:

```
WSGIRestrictStdout Off
```

to the top of
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com
and add

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

to my wsgi and add exception handles with the python print commands.

Comment: If you had to do that to stdout, you are using an ancient version of mod_wsgi. You should really upgrade. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/04/wsgi-and-printing-to-standard-output.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/debugging-with-pdb-when-using-modwsgi.html